# node_modules in Angular 7 CLI project is ~660Mb size on disk

Tags: angular, angular-cli, node-modules, angular-cli-v7

When I try to generate a brand new Angular CLI project (using ng new command), node_modules size is ~660Mb. 
I don't know why these resources grown that much since v6, where node_modules was about twice smaller.

How to optimize? Am I only one struggling with that? I can't believe 660Mb is the proper size. How about node_modules size in your projects?

node -v 10.1.0, npm -v 5.6.0, Win10x64

generated package.json below

```
{
  "name": "test7",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: No, you are not the only one struggling with this, and these 660Mb are simply obscene; just compare this absurd size for each project with Java's Maven dependency management. I put the following link not because I know anything about Turbo, but because at least the article does not pretend that the problem does not exist, and then there is this nice drawing of the "heaviest objects in the universe" :). https://medium.com/@ericsimons/introducing-turbo-5x-faster-than-yarn-npm-and-runs-natively-in-browser-cc2c39715403

Comment: But right now I am just doing what presumably the majority does, download the 660 or so Mb from NPM repository, and trust being the built and optimized Angular project artifacts to be not more than several Mb in size.